# Unable to open YII shell command line tool on xampp

Tags: yii

My **yiic.bat** file has set following

```
@echo off

rem -------------------------------------------------------------
rem  Yii command line script for Windows.
rem  This is the bootstrap script for running yiic on Windows.
rem -------------------------------------------------------------

@setlocal

set BIN_PATH=%~dp0

if "%PHP_COMMAND%" == "" set PHP_COMMAND=c:\xampp\php\php.exe

"%PHP_COMMAND%" "%BIN_PATH%yiic.php" %*

@endlocal
```

Now I can create any web application for yii

But I am unable to open yii shell comand line tool.

The problem is following in my cmd

**Error: index.php does not exist or is not an entry script file**

I've search this related question. But I could not find appropriate answer. 
Please ask, How can I configure my MyAplication/protected/yiic.bat file?
Thanks.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/1288-error-indexphp-does-not-exist-or-is-not-an-entry-script-file/
look at quiang's answer

Comment: but I can't sove this. I also use 'yiic shell' in parent protected directory. but I phase same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same problem but just solved!
You MUST type from INSIDE your webapp folder, because your index.php it's right there.
So:
**1)** go in you htdocs folder [cd c:\xampp\htdocs]
**2**)install your "SomeName" app typing directly: [Yii-1.1.13/framework/yiic webapp SomeName]
**3**)now go in your 'SomeName' folder [cd somename] (so you will be inside c:\xampp\htdocs\somename)
**4**) execute from here yiic by typing directly: [c:\xampp\htdocs\yii-1.1.13\framework\yiic shell]
**5**) you will read: "**Yii Interactive Tool v1.1
Please type 'help' for help. Type 'exit' to quit.**" - (if not, well... sorry!!)

If it works, that's because when you start the "yiic shell" command (**4**) you must be inside **c:\xampp\htdocs\somename** BECAUSE that's the folder where you find that "index.php" inside! So, for example, if you're inside [c:\xampp] and run [c:\xampp\htdocs\yii-1.1.13\framework\yiic shell] you will fail, because there's no "index.php" file inside [c:\xampp]! 
I hope I was clear! Good luck!

Comment: thanks for answer. I was solve this problem many days ago. your answer is right. may be this answer is helpful for another newbie

Answer (score 0):

Why not just run yiic directly from PHP?

```
C:\xampp\php\php.exe /path/to/yiic
```

Answer (score 0):

in cli move to your project/protected-folder, then:

yiic shell ../index.php

create your project with yiic in your framework-folder
create all project related things with yiic in your projects protected folder